# In jQM, what is the proper/correct/actual way to set fullscreen CSS image background for Page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

After a long time working on a jQM project, almost complete in functionality. Now working on UI. When I try to set full cover CSS image background for jQM Page, it either doesn't work as expected.

I google/stackoverflow a lot on this matter. To my surprise, there is no official documentation, direct/simple way to solve this problem.

Many suggestion will work for some people and not for others (even all in supported browser). For me, at first I can't get the 100% height, then after some google and help from other programmer, I can get the 100% height but now its bouncing background before and after transition.

The question for this post, is there any correct way/proper way, official way to set jQM Page background image WITHOUT all the PROBLEMs?

I'm sure this correct/proper/actual way can help and benefits many other developers.

Please advice, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/vds2U/51/

## Content background image

#### HTML

```
<div data-role="page" id="index" data-theme="a" >
    <div data-role="header">
        <h3>
            First Page
        </h3>
        <a href="#second" class="ui-btn-right">Next</a>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content" id="content">

    </div>

    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

    </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
#content {
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute !important;
    top : 40px !important; 
    right : 0;
    bottom : 0 !important; 
    left : 0 !important;  
    background:url(http://htc-wallpaper.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/bulldog-puppy1.jpg);
    background-size:cover;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;    
}
```

Read more about this solution **[here](http://www.gajotres.net/solution-to-jquery-mobile-page-content-empty-space-height-problem/)**.

## Page background image

#### CSS

```
.ui-page {
    background:url(http://htc-wallpaper.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/bulldog-puppy1.jpg);
    background-size:cover;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;    
}
```

Comment: Hi, your CSS example works but with some little problem. The page is a little bit scrollable even the page content is empty. I suspect it's because of the header and footer is external live out of the page's DIV. And also, the page with the BG Image is not the first page in my multipage html file. So, the reason may be caused by the miscalculation of the content height when it's without header and footer yet. I was thinking to refresh the content DIV before pageshow event. Will that work? If yes, may I know what is the function to refresh the content DIV? Please advice, thank you.

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle of this problem?

Comment: Hi @Gajotres, this is my jsfiddle for the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/lesliez/SL3XX/2/ I'm unable to regenerate the scroll problem but it does show some error on the background which I have the same problem. The background height wrongly calculated. Please advice what is wrong in my code. Thank you.